# Put VS Post VS Delete In Rest API

Tags: rest

I have a doubt on Http methods in Rest API.I read lot about over internet on this,that we can use Put for create or update the resource and Post for creating the resource and Delete for delete a resource.
But i am saying is this mandatory?because when we write code we just put the annotation like Put,Post and Delete but what would happen if I use Delete Annotation and in side method i do something else, suppose  i write add logic instead of delete.I think i can do it,similarly in others methods(Post and Put.).Then what is the significance of these Annotations.If i can do what i have mention above means write the logic for add in Delete Annotation then for me Delete is only a type of request for me and i can write any logic for add or update.

Similar i read Put is idempotent but if i write add logic instead of update then it is not idempotent.

May be i might be wrong here.Please clarify this.This is causing confusion to me and nowhere it is explained,Every where the generic statement there.

Thanks & Regards

Amitabh Pandey

Comment: REST is a protocol - whether you stick to the protocol or not is your decision, but don't expect others to be able to communicate with your application if you defer from the protocol. For simplicity reasons, "HTTP" is the English language and "REST" is the protocol of entering or exiting a house. Of course you can invent a protocol where "Can I exit your house" means "Can I come in" and "Can I enter your house" means "Where is the exit", but I guarantee a lot of confusion between you and your guests.

Comment: Thanks Smutje for your clarification by best example.

Answer (score 0):

> i am saying is this mandatory?

Not mandatory, no.

Roy Fielding made an interesting observation in [2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html):

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What
> it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe

The same holds for the other methods -- we all agree what the request message mean (semantics), because that's what is in the standards (RFC 7230, etc).  So PUT always means "please replace your current representation of the target resource with the representation I'm providing", but what your implementation does with that message is up to you.

Of course, if your implementation is surprising, there is an important caveat:

> it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property

The point of REST is that general-purpose components can interact with your resources via the uniform interface.  If your implementation doesn't match the uniform interface, then it's your bug, not a bug in the component, that things don't "just work".

> i read Put is idempotent but if i write add logic instead of update then it is not idempotent.

The semantics of PUT are [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2).  If your handler for PUT requests isn't idempotent, then you have made a mistake, and your implementation has a fault.  If a general purpose component needs to send multiple PUT messages (for instance, because a response was lost on an unreliable network), then that fault becomes a failure.

"Add logic" isn't necessarily not idempotent, of course -- think about adding a key and value to a dictionary; if you add the same key twice, that's the same as adding the key once.

```
d = {}
d[k] = v
d[k] = v # idempotent, because this is a no-op

e = {k:old}
if e[k] == old:
    e[k] == new:
if e[k] == old: # Again, idempotent, because the second copy of the message is a no-op
    e[k] == new
```

What's supposed to happen, if somebody sends a PUT request and you cannot ensure idempotent semantics, is that you should return a [405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5), and make sure that your response to [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7) doesn't claim that PUT is supported for that resource.